# With inheritance and access to the parent is something wrong?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, tkinter

With inheritance and access to the parent, widgets are some weird wrong. I Need to make three section with the same widget as shown in the code.

I don't know how could do that really makes sense. Have you an idea how could this be done in the smartest way ?

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Interface(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent,start, ver_part, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.start = start
        self.ver_part = ver_part
        parent.title("Interface Window")

        self.frame = tk.LabelFrame(parent, text="Verification Part - %s"%ver_part)
        self.button = tk.Button(self.frame, text="%s"%ver_part)

        self.frame.grid(row=0+start)
        self.button.grid(row=0+start)

class Main(Interface):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.button_run = tk.Button(parent, text="Run", command=self.on_run())
        self.button_run.grid(row=3)

    def on_run(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    int_a = Interface(root,0, "A")
    int_b = Interface(root,1, "B")
    int_c = Interface(root,2, "C")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: And what exactly is wrong with the widgets? I ran your code and there are three widgets that look the same, what should be weird?

Comment: if you want to do the same thing, would you do it just on this way ? Have you an idea how could this be done in the smartest way ?

Comment: Well that is largely opinion based, so off-topic for SO.I'm no expert in tkinter, but I suppose the code looks OK. Edit: you may want to consult http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if you need code review instead of a answer to a specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are giving one of your widgets a parent of `parent` rather than `self`.

Change this line:

```
self.frame = tk.LabelFrame(parent, text="Verification Part - %s"%ver_part)
```

to this:

```
self.frame = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Verification Part - %s"%ver_part)
```

Once you've done that you need to call `pack`, `place` or `grid` on the individual instances of `Interface`.

For example:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
    int_a.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    int_b.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    int_c.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
```